# How to add double curly braces in ${} Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

HTML

```
`${ 
    {{content}} == "a_string"?
    <body> sample body 1 </body>
    :
    <body> sample body 2 </body>
  }`
```

I can't seem to make the code above work. I'm trying to add an if else statement inside a template literal but I can't seem to get the if statement to work. Using normal string instead of the double curly braces works but my data resides within the double curly braces.

Comment: what are you using? Angular? handlebars?

Comment: Try `content == "a_string"`?

Answer (score 1):

When inside a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you don't need the handlebars, so the following code should work:

```js
`${ 
  content == "a_string"
    ? <body> sample body 1 </body>
    : <body> sample body 2 </body>
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

no need to use double curly braces just move your code to double cotes and use ternary operator.

`${content == 'a_string' ? "<body> sample body 1 </body>" : "<body> sample body 2 </body>" }`

Answer (score 0):

I can't get you point completely. But my understanding this code will work

```
`${ 
    content == "a_string"?
     <body> sample body 1 </body>
    :
   <body> sample body 2 </body>
  }`
```

Comment: A return statement in a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is not valid.

Comment: @Titulum i corrected my mistake.